# fgets( ) does not wait for user input?

Tags: c, io, user-input

I am reading input from the keyboard to store in variables.

```
char foo[BUFFER_SIZE];
printf("Enter your string");
fgets(foo, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
printf("Enter another thingy");
```

However, the program does not wait for user input and directly goes to the second printf(). How can I fix this? I tried using a while loop but then I reach an infinite loop...

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's not a duplicate, the other post has a `scanf()` causing the problem.

Comment: @iharob : I have seen your answer. But when writing on a terminal, stdout is always flushed before any read can occur. IMHO the only possibility is that there is a `\n` left in the input buffer. If OP explains that the cause is different I will revoke my close vote.

Comment: @SergeBallesta good point, I will check that and delete my answer accordingly.

Comment: @SergeBallesta you are totally right, This is what the standard says _Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream_

Comment: @iharob : your answer does not deserve to be deleted. It may not directly solve OP's problem, but there are plenty of worse ones around ;-)

Comment: Yes but it's misleading, and as a contributor to the site that I consider myself I delete it because it's wrong. I didn't know that because I never use `printf()` without `'\n'` unless I explicitly want the text to appear side by side. But I just learned something thanks to you.

Comment: Are you suggesting to flush stdin? Because I did use a scanf() in a block above, so maybe this is the cause?

Comment: @brvh Most likely. Do `getchar();` after the scanf to consume the `\n` left in the input stream.

Comment: @iharob The text you quoted talks about how streams are buffered. I don't see how that supports Serge's claim.

Comment: It means that at least the first `printf()` prints something before `fgets()`, my answer assumes that it's after. Most likely the `fgets()` reads something that is waiting on `stdin` to be read, like `'\n'` left from a previous `scanf()`, so this question shall be closed as off-topic because questions seeking debugging help ... etc.